# How to Display image in <img> element using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

```
[{
  "img_ID": 1,
  "ci_ID": 1,
  "ciCode": "CI_00001ID",
  "Title": "my_images_01",
  "Image": "C:\\Users\\SMG48\\Downloads\\Images\\wp2448691-jihyo-twice-wallpapers.jpg"
}]
```

Is there anyway to show the `Image` on the array in the `<img>` tag using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the function that make you get the array:

```
function displayImg(array) {
    var img;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        img = document.createElement('img');
        img.source(array[i]['Image']);
      document.appendChild(img); // if you want just to append to parent
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir :D

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Image` element on the fly using DOM API and attach it to DOM.

You can iterate over image response array, and add following code in your loop.

```
var someParentNode; // Some DOM Node
var images = [{
  "img_ID": 1,
  "ci_ID": 1,
  "ciCode": "CI_00001ID",
  "Title": "my_images_01",
  "Image": "C:\\Users\\SMG48\\Downloads\\Images\\wp2448691-jihyo-twice-wallpapers.jpg"
}]

images.forEach((img) => {

var IMG = document.createElement('img');
IMG.source(img.Image)

// append to parent. 
someParentNode.appendChild(IMG);
}
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp

Answer (score 0):

In your script:

```js
images = [{
  "img_ID": 1,
  "ci_ID": 1,
  "ciCode": "CI_00001ID",
  "Title": "my_images_01",
  "Image": "C:\\Users\\SMG48\\Downloads\\Images\\wp2448691-jihyo-twice-wallpapers.jpg"
}] //for each Images ________

images.forEach(function(element) {
  document.getElementById("img").src = element.Image;
});
```